# Spring Data Elastic named query from external file

Tags: elasticsearch, spring-data, spring-data-elasticsearch

In our project we need to manage Elasticsearch query in external file.
We work with Spring Data Elastic, so we can use `@Query`.
But I don't want to do it hard coded like this:

```
@Query("{"bool" : {"must" : {"field" : {"name" : "?0"}}}}")
```

I want to point on some external file:
and I see `@Query` has name parameter, but I can't find examples how it should work

This want I want:

application.properties:

```
my.query = {"bool" : {"must" : {"field" : {"name" : "?0"}}}}
```

And:

```
@Query(name = "my.query")
```

Or may be I should point to the name of the file where the query exists.
I found JPA examples, but how it can be done with elastic?
Any help will be every appriciated

Answer (score 0):

In the same way that you can configure the location of where to find the named queries properties file using `namedQueriesLocation` parameter in `EnableJpaRepositories` you can use the same parameter in `EnableElasticsearchRepositories`.

The other alternative is using the default location file `META-INF/elasticsearch-named-queries.properties`

Eg:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableElasticsearchRepositories(namedQueriesLocation = "classpath:*-named-queries.properties")
public class ElasticsearchConfiguration {
    ...
}
```